# find the pattern based on the parent distance from child

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've the below XML structure

```
<root>
<orderedlist>
<item num="1"><para num="1"></para>
<para num="2"></para>
</item>
<orderedlist>
</root>
```

I'm using the below XPath from `item` template

```
<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:apply-templates select="./para/node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
<li class="item">


      <xsl:for-each select="para">
      <div class="para">
      <xsl:choose>

<xsl:when test="name(../../parent::*[1]) = 'section'">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="../@num" mode="next"/>


</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>

<xsl:if test="../@num"/>
<span class="item-num">
<xsl:value-of select="../@num"/>
</span>
</xsl:otherwise>



</xsl:choose>

       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
    </li>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template mode="next" match="@num">



 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
<xsl:matching-substring>
         <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}"/>
    <span class="phrase">
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
<xsl:matching-substring>
         <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2))}"/>
    <span class="phrase">
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>

    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>

</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>


<!--   <xsl:apply-templates select="../para"/></div>
      </li>-->

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()) or normalize-space()])]"/>

 <xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <a name="{concat('pg_',./@num)}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

but it is true for both the `para`, but i want to select the `para` whose preceding is a parent, in other words i want to select so called immediate parent, in the above example i want to select `para num="1"` since it is the first child of `item`, i want to do this from `para` template.

please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `<xsl:template match="*/para[1]">...</xsl:template>` you have a template that matches only those `para` elements that are the first `para` child of their parent. Or with `<xsl:template match="item/para[1]">...</xsl:template>` the template matches only the first `para` child element of an `item` parent element.

If there are other child elements and you only want to match a `para` element if it is the first child element then use `<xsl:template match="item/*[1][self::para]">...</xsl:template>`.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I'm sorry for the wrong question asked, i want the template to be called from `item`, I've updated the template. Sorry and Thanks again.